# How to configure view width fixed width and variable height with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout, uikit

I have the following setup: a `UIView` containing a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`. The `UIButton` has fixed dimensions (it doesn't really matter). The `UILabel`, however, is constrained by the view's bounds.

I want to be able to set the `UIView`'s width and it should automatically resize itself so that its height allows the whole label content to be visible.

I have tried the following:

```
self.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, 0);
CGSize fittingSize = [self.view systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, fittingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
```

But this changes both the height **and the width** of the view, not keeping the width at the desired value.

Is there an elegant method to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help?

Comment: Right now your code has nothing to do with auto layout. Are you asking how you could archieve that with auto layout? if so, why are you posting that code? btw. you are setting the width of your view to `fittingSize.width` and wonder why it's affecting your view's width? why don't you do `self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, desiredWidth, fittingSize.height);`??

Comment: The UIView has auto layout constraints to layout the UILabel and the UIButton relative to their bounds.

I cannot set directly the `desiredWidth` because it has to match the `fittingSize.height`. (eg. if the `fittingSize.width` is very small, the `fittingSize.height` needs to be super tall)

Comment: so why are you hiding them from us? :P

Answer (score 0):

In AutoLayout, you would need add a width, top, bottom, leading (left) and/or trailing (right) constraints for the view on to the superview and declare properties for at least the top and/or bottom constraints. After adding the aforementioned constraints you could then change the height of the view by adjusting top and/or bottom constraints constant value.

Here is a link to the Auto Layout Guide.

[Auto Layout Guide: Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)